# Detect presence/absence of a ball in image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

What are best methods/techniques I can use to detect the presence/absence of a ball in an image?  I'm using grayscale cameras and am trying to prevent my Circle Hough Transform from producing false positives when there is no ball present in the scene.

Would it possible to achieve this using the average grayscale value of the scene and detecting an increase in this average value to detect the presence of a ball?

Many thanks everyone for your inputs in advance.

Comment: does the ball have a particular colour / texture ?

Comment: No, I'd like to achieve this independent of colour/texture, i.e. I'd like to use any soccer ball.

Comment: a matte ball bounces light nicely off itself and would be easier to track by colour. A soccer ball has the high contrast black/white pattern which should be easier to identify. For a general solution(regardless whether your object is a soccer ball or not), you might want to look into feature descriptors/detectors(SURF,SIFT,etc.). Another option could be training a haar/lbp cascade, although the training process is not super simple.

Comment: Although it would be easier to detect a ball using colour information, I can't rely on this since my application needs to detect any soccer ball.  Also, I am using grayscale cameras.

Comment: Just to make sure: are you applying your Circle Hough Transform to the result of some edge-detection algorithm on your original image?

Comment: Yes im using canny edge detector first before applying CHT.

Answer (score 1):

Computer Vision System Toolbox for MATLAB has a function called [trainCascadeObjectDetector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html) that lets you train your own Viola-Jones object detector.  There is also a [GUI app](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39627) on Matlab Central that helps you label the training data and tune the training parameters.